# Exclusive Disjunction

Tags: logic

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this question. Intuitively, I want to say that the rule of inference is invalid but I'm not entirely sure how to approach the question.

Thanks!

Comment: The rule is invalid. Hint: S ▽ T is false when both S and T are true.

Comment: Thank you! I understand when the rule is false, I'm having troubles coming up with the introduction and elimination rules.

Comment: "Exclusive disjunction" is more commonly known as exclusive OR or XOR. For how to get introduction/elimination rules for various connectives see [Zach's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05995.pdf), XOR is on p.11.

Answer (score 3):

If you tried formalizing what's going on with this it might look something like this:

```
{1}      1.  P ▽ Q                       Prem.
{1}      2.  P ∨ Q & ~(P & Q)            Def. ▽
{1}      3.  P ∨ Q                       2 &E
{4}      4.  P                           Assum (1st Disj.)
{4}      5.  S                           P → S
{4}      6.  S ∨ T                       5 ∨I (1st Concl.)
{7}      7.  Q                           Assum (2nd Disj.)
{7}      8.  T                           Q → T
{7}      9.  S ∨ T                       8 ∨I (2nd Concl.)
{1}      10. S ∨ T                       3,4,6,7,9 EE
{1}      11. ~(P & Q)                    2 &E
{1}      12. ~P ∨ ~Q                     11 DM
{13}     13. ~P                          Assum. (1st Disj.)
{13}     14. ~S                          INVALID !!!!!!
{13}     15. ~S ∨ ~T                     14 ∨I (1st Concl.)
{16}     16. ~Q                          Assum. (2nd Disj.)
{16}     17. ~T                          INVALID !!!!!!
{16}     18. ~S ∨ ~T                     17 ∨I (2nd Concl.)
{1}      19. ~S ∨ ~T                     12,13,15,16,17 EE
{1}      20. ~(S & T)                    19 DM
{1}      21. S ∨ T & ~(S & T)            10,20 &I
{1}      22. S ▽ T                       21 Def. ▽
```

This proof is invalid because of lines 14 and 17. The question suggests that P → S and Q → T, but there's no reason to assume that ~P → ~S or ~Q → ~T. There's no way to prove ~(S & T), so that would be an example of how it is invalid.

**Introduction and Elimination Rules**

The introduction rule would simply be applying the definition as I did on line 22:

```
A ∨ B & ~(A & B)
A ▽ B
```

For elimination, consider the fact that the following are logically equivalent:

- (A ▽ B) → C
- ((A ∨ B) & ~(A & B)) → C
- ((A ∨ B) → C) ∨ ((~A ∨ ~B) → C)

This logical characteristics of the last expression are as follows:

```
A  B  C  |  ((A  ∨  B) →  C) ∨ ((~  A  ∨  ~  B) →  C)
-----------------------------------------------------
0  0  0  |    0  0  0  1  0  1   1  0  1  1  0  0  0   
0  0  1  |    0  0  0  1  1  1   1  0  1  1  0  1  1   
0  1  0  |    0  1  1  0  0  0   1  0  1  0  1  0  0   
0  1  1  |    0  1  1  1  1  1   1  0  1  0  1  1  1   
1  0  0  |    1  1  0  0  0  0   0  1  1  1  0  0  0   
1  0  1  |    1  1  0  1  1  1   0  1  1  1  0  1  1   
1  1  0  |    1  1  1  0  0  1   0  1  0  0  1  1  0   
1  1  1  |    1  1  1  1  1  1   0  1  0  0  1  1  1
```

Therefore, given A ▽ B, if C can be concluded from either A  ∨  B or ~A ∨ ~B, then (A ▽ B) ⊢ C.  This can be depicted as follows:

```
A ▽ B
| A
| C
----
| B
| C
C
```

If that fails, then you can try the other:

```
A ▽ B
| ~A
| C
----
| ~B
| C
C
```

**Elimination with two different paths?**

It might seem counterintuitive to have an elimination rule that can be applied in more than one way. However, AND elimination also shares this pattern. Consider that the following two expression are logically equivalent:

- (A & B) → C
- (A → C) ∨ (B → C)

That is to say that the conclusion can follow from the first conjunct *or* it can follow from the second. Therefore, there are two alternatives with AND elimination as well:

```
A & B
A
```

If that's not what you wanted apply the other:

```
A & B
B
```

**An example of XOR elimination**

Usually it would only be necessary to apply XOR elimination to one of the conjuncts. However, in the following example, it is applied twice. The first (R ∨ (~Q → S)) is applied on line 4, and it ends on line 8 with the conclusion Q. The second (~R ∨ ~(~Q → S)) begins on line 9 and ends on line 16 with the conclusion ~S ∨ ~R. These two are then combined for the final conclusion of the proof.

Notice that it is applied exactly like OR elimination to each of the conjuncts.

```
R ▽ (~Q → S), ~Q → ~R, ~S ⊢ (S → ~R) & Q

{1}      1.  R ▽ (~Q → S)                     Prem.
{2}      2.  ~Q → ~R                          Prem.
{3}      3.  ~S                               Prem.
{4}      4.  R                                Assum. (1st Disj.)
{2,4}    5.  Q                                2,4 MT (1st Concl.)
{6}      6.  ~Q → S                           Assum. (2nd Disj.)
{3,6}    7.  Q                                3,6 MT (2nd Concl.)
{1,2,3}  8.  Q                                1,4,5,6,7 ▽E
{9}      9.  ~R                               Assum. (1st Disj.)
{9}      10.  ~S ∨ ~R                         9 ∨I (1st Concl.)
{11}     11. ~(~Q → S)                        Assum. (2nd Disj.)
{11}     12. ~(Q ∨ S)                         11 MI
{11}     13. ~Q & ~S                          12 DN
{11}     14. ~S                               13 &E
{11}     15. ~S ∨ ~R                          14 ∨I (2nd Concl.)
{1}      16. ~S ∨ ~R                          1,9,10,11,15 ▽E
{1}      17. S → ~R                           16 MI
{1,2,3}  18. (S → ~R) & Q                     7,17 &I
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, it really cleared things up! For the elimination rules, do you mean we would need A → C and ~B → C so that we can validly infer C (and vice versa for ~A and B)?

This is what I take it you are saying but I just want to double check.

Comment: You would treat it just like disjunction elimination with A ∨ B to prove some conclusion C, and if that doesn't work, you can do disjunction elimination with ~A ∨ ~B to prove the same conclusion C. It's really a matter of resolving the expression (A ∨ B) & (~A ∨ ~B). And just like AND elimination, either side of the & operator can lead to a valid conclusion.

Comment: In other words, (A ∨ B) & (~A ∨ ~B) is logically identical to A ▽ B. Therefore, the elimination rule is like first applying AND elimination to obtain A ∨ B, and then you would use OR elimination just like normal. Or, you can obtain ~A ∨ ~B and do OR elimination with it.

Comment: The way you worded it is incorrect, because it would be A → C and B → C to conclude C. Then afterward ~A → C and ~B → C to conclude the same C.

Comment: Ok I believe I understand what you are saying, I guess my confusion stems from the fact that if you just use regular OR elimination with (A v B), then that does not rules out the possibility that A and B are both true. For a valid inference of C from A ▽ B, wouldn't you need to show that (A v B) → C and (~A v ~B) → C and only then would it be valid to infer C? Is this what you mean? I am a little confused as to whether you are saying the lone OR elimination of (A v B) → C would suffice to make a valid inference of C.

Comment: Oh I now see where my error in logic is coming from with the OR elimination. I am still a little unclear though as to when it would be valid to infer C from A ▽ B. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: There's two things to notice with that. **First**, the example in the question is invalid as I said because you really can't prove S ▽ T which would require proving  ~(S & T). However, that is associated with the conclusion and not the initial premise. With a premise of A ▽ B, it's not necessary to worry about proving the expression ~(A & B) because that is actually part of the premise. It's given to you.

Comment: **Second**, it helps to study the truth table I posted. Remember that the cases in which the premises is true is a subset of (or equal to) the cases of where the conclusion is true. In other words, for every row where the premise is true, the conclusion must be true, but the conclusion may be true for more rows than the premises.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am going to take a few minutes to rethink my approach and see if it doesn't make more sense with those points in mind. I have one last question: If we are given A ▽ B and A, can't an elimination rule be to infer ~B from this? Since based on their truth tables, wouldn't A ▽ B be the negation of the biconditional?

Comment: Yes, you can conclude that. Select the second conjunct ~A ∨ ~B, and using OR elimination, you can conclude ~B, because (A & ~A) → ~B, and ~B → ~B.

Comment: I am still not quite grasping how the disjunction elimination would provide a valid inference of C. I've taken a look at the truth table and I'm not sure exactly what the premise/conclusion is. I understand that ~(A & B) is part of the premise, but we would still need to show that it is satisfied no? Otherwise wouldn't the elimination rule just be the same as the inclusive OR which would not work for exclusive OR. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something in your explanations. Either way, I appreciate the explanations, they helped greatly.

Comment: You don't need to *satisfy* any part of the premise in any way; rather, *any* part of the premise is sufficient if the inference is valid. This can be seen with AND elimination: (A & B & C) → B. If B is all that I need to conclude, I can forget about A and C. In the same way with (A ∨ B) & (~A ∨ ~B), if A ∨ B implies the conclusion I need, I can forget about the other conjunct ~A ∨ ~B. There's nothing special about the  elimination rule; you can simply substitute (A ∨ B) & (~A ∨ ~B) for A ▽ B, and proceed as you normally would with the traditional rules.

Comment: I edited the answer to give an example of its application. As I show in the example, XOR elimination can be applied more than once so that whatever can't be concluded from A ∨ B can be concluded from ~A ∨ ~B. In that way, all the implications of the original premise A ▽ B can be utilized.